# py2neo query returns None, but same query works on neo4j console

Tags: neo4j, py2neo

I have the following code:

```
def get_post(self, post_id):
        user = self.find()
        query = """
        MATCH   (user:User {id: {user_id}})-[:PUBLISHED]->(post:Post {id: {post_id}})
        RETURN  post
        """

        post = graph.run(query, user_id=user['id'], post_id=post_id)[0]

        return post
```

The problem is that `graph.run()` returns `None`, even when there is a node that matches the condition, as you can see in this snapshot of **neo4j** console (I substituted binding variables for actual values, and I verified that such values are right when the failing call is made):

[image]

I don't know if I am using binding variables properly, or what is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the problem is that `graph.run()` returns a **cursor**, so you must traverse it in order to get access to its content. So the this is the actual functional code:

```
def get_post(self, post_id):
    user = self.find()
    query = """
    MATCH   (user:User {id:{user_id}})-[r:PUBLISHED]->(post:Post {id:{post_id}})
    RETURN  post
    """
    post = graph.run(query, user_id=user['id'], post_id=post_id)
    if post.forward():
        return post.current['post']
    else:
        return None
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `graph.data()` instead of `graph.run()` too.

```
def get_post(self, post_id):
    user = self.find()
    query = """
    MATCH   (user:User {id:{user_id}})-[r:PUBLISHED]->(post:Post {id:{post_id}})
    RETURN post AS result
    """
    posts = graph.data(query, user_id=user['id'], post_id=post_id)
    for node in posts:
        print node["result"]
```